# Page fault with newlib functions

Tags: porting, page-fault, newlib

I've been porting newlib to my very small kernel, and I'm stumped: whenever I *include* a function that references a system call, my program will page fault on execution. If I call a function that does not reference a system call, like `rand()`, nothing will go wrong.

Note: By include, I mean as long as the function, e.g. `printf()` or `fopen()`, is somewhere inside the program, even if it isn't called through `main()`.

I've had this problem for quite some time now, and have no idea what could be causing this:

- I've rebuilt newlib numerous times
- Modified my ELF loader to load the
  code from the section headers instead of program headers
- Attempted to build newlib/libgloss separately (which failed)
- Linked the libraries (libc, libnosys) through the ld script using `GROUP`, gcc and ld

I'm not quite sure what other information I should include with this, but I'd be happy to include what I can.

Edit: To verify, the page faults occurring are not at the addresses of the failing functions; they are elsewhere in the program. For example, when I call `fopen()`, located at 0x08048170, I will page fault at 0xA00A316C.

Edit 2:
Relevant code for loading ELF:

```
int krun(u8int *name) {
    int fd = kopen(name); 
    Elf32_Ehdr *ehdr = kmalloc(sizeof(Elf32_Ehdr*));
    read(fd, ehdr, sizeof(Elf32_Ehdr));

    if (ehdr->e_ident[0] != 0x7F || ehdr->e_ident[1] != 'E' || ehdr->e_ident[2] != 'L' || ehdr->e_ident[3] != 'F') {
        kfree(ehdr);
        return -1; 
    }

    int pheaders    = ehdr->e_phnum;
    int phoff       = ehdr->e_phoff;
    int phsize      = ehdr->e_phentsize;

    int sheaders    = ehdr->e_shnum;
    int shoff       = ehdr->e_shoff;
    int shsize      = ehdr->e_shentsize; 

    for (int i = 0; i < pheaders; i++) {
        lseek(fd, phoff + phsize * i, SEEK_SET);

        Elf32_Phdr *phdr = kmalloc(sizeof(Elf32_Phdr*));
        read(fd, phdr, sizeof(Elf32_Phdr)); 

        u32int page = PMMAllocPage();

        int flags = 0; 
        if (phdr->p_flags & PF_R) flags |= PAGE_PRESENT;
        if (phdr->p_flags & PF_W) flags |= PAGE_WRITE; 

        int pages = (phdr->p_memsz / 0x1000) + 1;
        while (pages >= 0) {
            u32int mapaddr = (phdr->p_vaddr + (pages * 0x1000)) & 0xFFFFF000; 
            map(mapaddr, page, flags | PAGE_USER); 
            pages--; 
        }

        lseek(fd, phdr->p_offset, SEEK_SET);
        read(fd, (void *)phdr->p_vaddr, phdr->p_filesz);   

        kfree(phdr);
    }

    // Removed: code block that zeroes .bss: it's already zeroed whenever I check it anyways
    // Removed: code block that creates thread and adds it to scheduler 

    kfree(ehdr);                
    return 0; 
}
```

Edit 3: I've noticed that if I call a system call, such as `write()`, and then call `printf()` two or more times, I will get an unknown opcode interrupt. Odd.

Comment: Can you run the moral equivalent of `ldd /path/to/binary` on a working and on a failing executable?

Comment: @sarnold I ran `objdump` and `readelf` (my environment doesn't have `ldd`); there is no dynamic section, relocations or unwind sections in either executable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whoops! Figured it out: when I map the virtual address, I should allocate a new page each time, like so:

```
map(mapaddr, PMMAllocPage(), flags | PAGE_USER);
```

Now it works fine.

For those curious as to why it didn't work: when I wasn't including `printf()`, the size of the program was under 0x1000 bytes, so mapping with only one page was okay. When I include `printf()` or `fopen()`, the size of the program was much bigger so that's what caused the issue.